# Fundamental solution matrix of a linear PDE

Tags: linear-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I've asked a very similar question also at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774362/153451), but I've not received any answer.

A vectorial function $\boldsymbol{x}:\mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ satisfies the following linear PDE

$$
\sum_{i=1}^D c_i \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{x}(t_1, \dots, t_D)}{\partial t_i}
    = \boldsymbol{A}(t_1, \dots, t_D) \boldsymbol{x}(t_1, \dots, t_D).
$$

The scalars $c_i$ are constant, and $\boldsymbol{A}(t_1, \dots, t_D): \mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is quasiperiodic, i.e.

$$
\boldsymbol{A}(t_1, \dots, t_i+T_i, \dots, t_D)
    = \boldsymbol{A}(t_1, \dots, t_i, \dots, t_D).
$$

Which boundary conditions should I impose in order to numerically find one of its fundamental solution matrices?

Comment: Since the $c_i$ are constant (as you say over at math.SE), you can choose coordinates $(s_i)$ such that $\partial/\partial s_1 = \sum_i^D c_i \partial/\partial t_i$. Then your PDE is just an ODE in $s_1$ with $D-1$ parameters. This reduces the PDE boundary conditions to $(s_2,\ldots, s_D)$-parametrized ODE initial/boundary conditions. Perhaps this is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It's the same that has been written in JA Murdock - On the Floquet Problem for Quasiperiodic Systems. I'll try to think about it.